eroor while compile android kernel source
I want to a add a driver in Android kernel source code. Before I added the driver, the source compile perfectly. But after I added the driver rtl8188eus in drivers/stagging and modify Makefile and Kconfig, it show the following error:
  LD      drivers/staging/prima/wlan.o
  LD      drivers/staging/prima/built-in.o
make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:653: drivers/staging] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/root/nethunter_kernel_redmi_6_pro_sakura/Makefile:1138: drivers] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/nethunter_kernel_redmi_6_pro_sakura/out'
make: *** [Makefile:152: sub-make] Error 2
root@AWM:~/nethunter_kernel_redmi_6_pro_sakura#


here my kernel source:- https://github.com/dek0der/nethunter_kernel_redmi_6_pro_sakura.git
here the driver :- https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus.git

But someone doing the same thing https://github.com/SakuraSource/kernel_xiaomi_sakura.git and I clone it and try to compile and its compiled without error. Now I can't understand where I have made the mistake. Can anyone please explain?

The part of the log you show just tells that some error has been occurred. The error message is somewhere above in the log.

but i see all logs with my code to  https://github.com/SakuraSource/kernel_xiaomi_sakura.git that working code and everything is sililar still get error in my code and compiled in https://github.com/SakuraSource/kernel_xiaomi_sakura.git that code please help
